# skimage.transform.warp vs cv2.warpPerspective

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image, homography

This is a topic that has also struck me recently, namely the differences between *skimage* geometric transforms and their equivalences in *opencv*. My goal is to replace the `skimage.transform.warp` function in the following example. Just from the basic look of it, they work similarly and  `borderMode` or `borderValue` are also the same by default, yet I don't receive the same result. What am I missing?

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform
import cv2

img = np.random.rand(16,16)

angle = np.deg2rad(45)
cos_a, sin_a = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
R = np.array([[cos_a, sin_a, -11 * (cos_a + sin_a - 1)],
             [-sin_a, cos_a, -11 * (cos_a - sin_a - 1)],
             [0, 0, 1]])

skimage_rotated = skimage.transform.warp(img, R, clip=False)
cv2_rotated = cv2.warpPerspective(img, R, dsize=skimage_rotated.shape)

print(np.count_nonzero(np.where(np.abs(skimage_rotated - cv2_rotated) > 1e-1)))) #356

plt.imshow(np.abs(skimage_rotated - cv2_rotated))
plt.show()
```

[image: np.abs(skimage_rotated - cv2_rotated)]

Comment: "not 0" says very little. show us the per pixel absolute differences as a picture. opencv uses fixed point math for execution speed.

Comment: the results are entirely different, not just differing by tiny amounts. you should try with `cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"))` or anything that contains more structure than pure noise. look at the result of each transformation. compare with your own eyes.

Comment: Can you add a colorbar to the image? What's the dynamic range we're seeing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `skimage.transform.warp` performs backward transformation and `cv2.warpPerspective` performs forward transformation.

Passing `cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP` flag to `cv2.warpPerspective` solves the issue. (we may also invent the transformation matrix):

```
cv2_rotated = cv2.warpPerspective(img, R, dsize=skimage_rotated.shape, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR+cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
```

---

Documentation of [skimage.transform.warp](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.warp):

> skimage.transform.warp(image, **inverse_map**, map_args=None, ...
> inverse_maptransformation object, callable cr = f(cr, **kwargs), or ndarray
> **Inverse** coordinate map, which transforms coordinates in the output images into their corresponding coordinates in the input image.

Documentation of [cv2.warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87):

> The function warpPerspective transforms the source image...
> when the flag **WARP_INVERSE_MAP** is set. Otherwise, the transformation is first **inverted** with invert and then put in the formula above instead of M.

---

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = np.random.rand(16,16).astype(np.float32)

angle = np.deg2rad(45)
cos_a, sin_a = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
R = np.array([[cos_a, sin_a, -11 * (cos_a + sin_a - 1)],
             [-sin_a, cos_a, -11 * (cos_a - sin_a - 1)],
             [0, 0, 1]])

skimage_rotated = skimage.transform.warp(img, R, clip=False)

#invR = np.linalg.inv(R)
#cv2_rotated = cv2.warpPerspective(img, invR, dsize=skimage_rotated.shape)
cv2_rotated = cv2.warpPerspective(img, R, dsize=skimage_rotated.shape, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR+cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)

print(np.count_nonzero(np.where(np.abs(skimage_rotated - cv2_rotated) > 1e-1))) #0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.abs(skimage_rotated - cv2_rotated))
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

---

`np.abs(skimage_rotated - cv2_rotated)`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's demonstrate geometric transformation by estimating homography matrix with an image, using `opencv-python`, `scikit-image` `transform` module's  `warp()` and `ProjectiveTransform()`, also let's compare the time complexities.

Let's use the following image (`'books.jpg'`) as input and the following source / destination point pairs to estimate the homography:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

im_src = plt.imread('books.jpg')
height, width, dim = im_src.shape
# src points from the source image 
# correspond to dst points in the target image
src = np.array([[267., 364.],
       [312., 683.],
       [555., 598.],
       [561., 284.]], dtype='float32')
dst = np.array([[   0.,    0.],
       [0, height-1],
       [width-1, height-1],
       [width-1, 0.]], dtype='float32')
```

with `opencv-python` using jupyter magic `%timeit`:

```
import cv2
%timeit M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
# 8.43 µs ± 677 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit im_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, M, (width, height), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
# 10.8 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

with `skimage.transform.warp()`, note that it expects inverse of `M`:

```
from skimage.transform import warp, ProjectiveTransform
%timeit im_dst = warp(im_src, np.linalg.inv(M), clip=False)
# 194 ms ± 19.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

with `skimage.transform.ProjectiveTransform()` (note that the x, y coordinates of the points are needed to be swapped):

```
def warp_projective(src_pts: np.ndarray, dst_pts: np.ndarray, im_src: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    src, dst = src_pts[:, [1, 0]], dst_pts[:, [1, 0]]
    pt = ProjectiveTransform()
    pt.estimate(src, dst)
    x, y = np.mgrid[:height, :width]
    dst_indices = np.hstack((x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1,1))) 
    src_indices = np.round(pt.inverse(dst_indices), 0).astype(int)
    valid_idx = np.where((src_indices[:,0] < height) & (src_indices[:,1] < width) & (src_indices[:,0] >= 0) & (src_indices[:,1] >= 0))
    dst_indicies_valid = dst_indices[valid_idx]
    src_indicies_valid = src_indices[valid_idx]
    im_dst[dst_indicies_valid[:,0],dst_indicies_valid[:,1]] = im_src[src_indicies_valid[:,0],src_indicies_valid[:,1]]
    return im_dst.astype(np.uint8) 
    
%timeit im_dst = warp_projective(src, dst, im_src)
# 123 ms ± 5.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

All the above three different implementations yield the same output as shown below:

[image]